# Unable to run truffle@2.1.2 migrate --network live. "Exceeds block gas limit"

Tags: ethereum, truffle, consensys-truffle, parity-io

I am using truffle@2.1.2 to deploy smart contracts against a `localhost:8545` `geth@1.5.9-stable` rpc, using an account that is funded with Ether has been unlocked using `personal.unlockAccount` on the geth console.

I have also tried the same against a remote Parity node via RPC, but this is the latest which I am rather stuck with.

**truffle.js**

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    "index.html": "index.html",
    "app.js": [
      "javascripts/app.js"
    ],
    "app.css": [
      "stylesheets/app.css"
    ],
    "images/": "images/"
  },
  rpc: {
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8545
  },
  networks: {
    "ropsten": {
      network_id: 3,
      port: 8548, // ssh tunnelled to AWS geth/parity node localhost:8545
      from: "0x4f000Bcf4641E2fDcE85BF26A694b053996850D4"
    },
    "live": {
      network_id: 1,
      port: 8545,
      from: "0x00269400181f1B379784BD8cDF786bb20e91Bdef",
      gas: 4612388,
      gasPrice: 2776297000 // taken from Parity startup log message "Updated conversion rate to Ξ1 = US$42.88 (2776297000 wei/gas)"
    }
  }
};
```

**truffle migrate --network live**

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Exceeds block gas limit
    at Object.module.exports.InvalidResponse (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
    at request.onreadystatechange (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:114:13)
    at dispatchEvent (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
    at setState (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:447:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

I have tried adjusting gas and gasPrice, but am unable to find values that have any affect.

**How can I solve this problem, or are there alternative contract deployment methods I should look into?**

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this by simply setting `gas: 3000000` in the network config.

```
"live": {
  network_id: 1,
  port: 8545,
  from: "0x00269400181f1B379784BD8cDF786bb20e91Bdef",
  gas: 3000000
}
```

It cost about 0.5 ETH to run migrations and took several minutes.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was generated by a user's empty balance.

so check your balances using the following function :

```
function checkAllBalances() {
    var totalBal = 0;
    for (var acctNum in eth.accounts) {
        var acct = eth.accounts[acctNum];
        var acctBal = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(acct), "ether");
        totalBal += parseFloat(acctBal);
        console.log("  eth.accounts[" + acctNum + "]: \t" + acct + " \tbalance: " + acctBal + " ether");
    }
    console.log("  Total balance: " + totalBal + " ether");
};
 checkAllBalances();
```

if the balance is 0 mine some blocks or edit your genesis file.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the same problem by indicate the network id when calling truffle,as:

```
truffle migrate --network live
```

and you should modify "from" tag in truffle.js with your unlocked account.

Comment: In the question I explain that I am already doing both of your suggestions, and still getting the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> **Simple solution:** : add gas: 500000 ,(don`t forget to add comma at the last)  in **truffle.js**

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8001,
      network_id: 1234, // Match any network id
      gas: 500000
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: a comma before gas (the end of the previous line "network...") is needed actually.